# How to find a US lawyer for consultation in the open-source + banking + blockchain space?

Tags: united-states, open-source-software, banking, cryptocurrency, blockchain

Considering writing open-source software in the banking/cryptocurrency space (in the USA). Want to do it properly, and have a few questions for how to navigate the space.

What's the type of lawyer I need to talk to and how do I find them?

Comment: You should edit your post to include the questions you have and/or specify what exactly you envision from your project.

Comment: @IñakiViggers there's too many questions. I'm just looking for the type of consultant at this point.

Comment: "*there's too many questions.*" That is too ambiguous and requires us to speculate the type of lawyer you need.

Comment: @IñakiViggers FTC/SEC + banking regulation in the US?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find a lawyer to hire](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/84487/how-to-find-a-lawyer-to-hire)

Comment: @user1147844 No, my question is more specific than that.